# SEO help: Lists do not contain only <li> elements and script supporting elements (<script> and <template>)

Tags: pagespeed-insights, accessibility-api

Page Speed Insights is giving me the following error message for Accessibility:

Lists do not contain only li elements and script supporting elements (script and template)

Below are the code snippets that are generating this message. I'm not quite sure what needs to be done here to stop generating the errors, any advice would be much appreciated!

```
    <ul class="slide_tit swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets">
```

```
    <li class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 1">
```

```
    <li class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 2">
```

```
    <li class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 3">
```

Comment: What are the contents of these elements? With that I mean the actual HTML, not the text itself.

Comment: @Caramiriel Sorry, just edited my post to include the code generating these errors

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the accessibility standard-- you can read more about this specific point [at deque University](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.4/list).

It looks like you're using the <li> elements as buttons for a carousel: a better method for creating accessible carousels [is here](https://dev.to/jasonwebb/how-to-build-a-more-accessible-carousel-or-slider-35lp) -- generally, you should avoid using list markup on slides. Screen Readers announce how many items will be on a list, but if you hide certain elements it will be inaccurate.

Be sure to close your <li> elements, and you should not include any content other than paragraphs, links etc between the opening and closing <li>-- that's what the error means. If you're using the lists for a purpose that isn't a list, use a different element.

Comment: In addition to Jess' answer, I think the role of the `<li>` items is being changed to buttons based on your `role="button"` attribute in there. Therefore, for ARIA purposes, they are no longer list items, but are now buttons